# Sprout Forms: Localized version of form with translated labels?

Tags: localization, form, plugin-sproutforms

Does  the **[Sprout Forms](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs)** plugin tap into the [internationalization feature](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/localization-guide) of Craft Pro, i.e. does it support **adding localized versions of existing forms**, similar to translated section entries?

What I'm looking for is creating forms where *all field names and values* are identical between language variants, but *labels and notifications* may differ per locale. (This is opposed to setting up multiple forms that are not tied together and write to separate tables in the back-end.)

In the [docs](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs), all I can find is a reference to [translated *error messages*](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/examples/translating-error-messages), which are the smallest of my concerns. — That same approach might work for the main conent of the form as well, but it could not be managed via the plugin's control panel.

Comment: For labels I just used global fields and hardcoded the whole form. For those translated notifications I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, Sprout Forms (v1.1.0) is translatable, but we have not yet added support for Craft's localization feature.

You can find a [template of a translation file](https://github.com/BarrelStrength/Sprout-Plugin-Translations) on our Github Account.

We want to support localization in the long run. The main reason we have not yet is mostly just one of priority. In comparison to other advanced features, we have had very few requests for it (feel free to send us a note and advocate for how this needs to work for you) and development for it isn't documented anywhere (feel free to send Pixel and Tonic a request for documenting it better too!). At the time of this posting, I posted a question here about the topic 7 months ago [February 2015] and the question has received one upvote and 41 views:

[How do you add support to manage content in multiple languages in a plugin with a custom Element Type?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/7124/how-do-you-add-support-to-manage-content-in-multiple-languages-in-a-plugin-with)

Comment: Any updates on this? Have an upcoming project where this would come in handy as well.

Comment: Still on the list, and the answer above is still more or less accurate.

Answer (score 1):

What about [translation files](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/static-translations).