# Localized ElementTypes in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, localization

My question is re: localization of ElementTypes in a plugin.  I have the records all working fine in multiple locales.

The part that I'm not "getting" is I think there should be one Element in `craft_elements` and then for each localization, there should be one record in `craft_elements_i18n` yes?  And then for each localization, there should be a separate record in my `craft_seomatic_meta` table for each localized version yes?

This is where in my controller it saves the ElementType: https://github.com/khalwat/seomatic/blob/master/controllers/SeomaticController.php#L173

And here is the function is calls in my service to save the element & record: https://github.com/khalwat/seomatic/blob/master/services/SeomaticService.php#L683

When I call `$result = craft()->elements->getElementById($metaId, 'Seomatic_Meta', $locale);` how does it "know" which record to look up to load the returned `Seomatic_MetaElementType` with data?

I'm clearly missing something basic regarding how this should all work

Answer (score 5):

> The part that I'm not "getting" is I think there should be one Element in craft_elements and then for each localization, there should be one record in craft_elements_i18n yes?

Yes.

> And then for each localization, there should be a separate record in my craft_seomatic_meta table for each localized version yes?

Only if the values in that table need to be stored on a per-locale basis, which to my knowledge has never been the case until now with SEOmatic.

> When I call $result = craft()->elements->getElementById($metaId, 'Seomatic_Meta', $locale); how does it "know" which record to look up to load the returned Seomatic_MetaElementType with data?

Any time you run an element query (which `getElementById()` does), the element type’s [`modifyElementsQuery()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/elementtypes/IElementType#modifyElementsQuery-detail) method will be called, which gives the element type a chance to make changes to the query. In [yours](https://github.com/khalwat/seomatic/blob/master/elementtypes/Seomatic_MetaElementType.php#L156), you have the following code:

```
$query
    ->addSelect('seomatic_meta.*')
    ->join('seomatic_meta seomatic_meta', 'seomatic_meta.elementid = elements.id')
    ->andWhere(DbHelper::parseParam('seomatic_meta.locale', $criteria->locale, $query->params));
```

That condition you’re adding to the query on the `seomatic_meta.locale` column is what is ensuring that the correct localized row in your `seomatic_meta` table will be included in the result.

That’s just for *selecting* elements though. I might be missing something, but looking at your [SeomaticService::saveMeta()](https://github.com/khalwat/seomatic/blob/master/services/SeomaticService.php#L683) method, it doesn’t look like you’re ever ensuring that all of the localized rows are actually getting saved. If you take a look through [ElementsService::saveElement()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/ElementsService#saveElement-detail), you will see that one of the things it does is loop through the locales returned by `$element->getLocales()` and make sure that there’s an ElementLocaleRecord (elements_i18n row) for the element in each of those locales. If you want to store rows for each locale in your own craft_seomatic_meta table, it’s the plugin’s responsibility to do that, not Craft’s.

Comment: I was planning to store different data on a per-locale basis, just as I do with my regular old records.  You saying that no one else has needed/wanted to do this makes me think that I'm doing something wrong?

Should I not be storing this data in my own table?  The "normal" way to do this would be to make a FieldType, and just have Craft handle the gory details, storing it in `craft_content`?

I feel like perhaps I'm doing something wrong, if it's something no one else is doing.

Comment: @khalwat No to be clear I think you’re going about it the right way. This is just the first plugin (that I can think of) that needs to provide fields that store _content_, but not via custom fields.

Comment: @khalwat: If it makes you feel better, I've recently gotten the feature request to make Smart Map's "Address" field translatable... But Brandon's right, AFAIK you're the first plugin dev to actually _try_ it. This is all great info, thanks to both of you guys!

Comment: @BrandonKelly - Above you say that we can add support for grabbing a particular locale using the `modifyElementsQuery()` method.  You point to the example coding adding an `andWhere` clause to do so. In looking at the `EntryElementType` and `CategoryElementType`, neither of those Elements seems to be limiting the result by locale in the `modifyElementsQuery()` method.  Why are the above example and the Entry and Category Elements different? What am I missing?

Comment: @BenParizek Because none of the built-in element types need to store data on a per-locale basis, besides whatever’s in `elements_i18n` and `content` (and those tables are already joined in before modifyElementsQuery() is even called).